# Conditional independence given the complement of an event

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Suppose $A_1,\ldots A_n$ are conditionally independent given $B$. Are they conditionally independent given $B^c$ as well?

Answer (score 5):

Counterexample: Consider the following visual obtained from wikipedia
[image]